# error with a private static variable

Tags: java

I have a class that has a private static variable,

```
private static counter = 0;
```

but it gives an error when I compile it:

Car.java:3:  <identifier>  expected

```
private static counter = 0;
                      ^
```

Does anyone know why it does this?  I don't understand what's wrong with it.

Here's the whole code:

```
public class Car
{
    private static counter = 0;
    private String name;

    public Car()
    {
    name = "car" +counter;
    counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the type. It seems that you mean

`private static int count = 0;`

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify type of variable

```
private static int counter = 0;
```